# How do I implement a 2D-DWT in a keras CNN architecture?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am trying to implement on a CNN a 2D-DWT (Discrete Wavelet Transform) block, which takes a tensor in input and gives four different outputs: an approximation and three details:

```
   import numpy as np
   import pywt

   data = np.ones((4,4), dtype=np.float64)
   coeffs = pywt.dwt2(data, 'haar')
   cA, (cH, cV, cD) = coeffs

   output: 

   tensor([[[2.0000, 2.0000],
            [2.0000, 2.0000]],

           [[0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0000, 0.0000]],

           [[0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0000, 0.0000]],

            [[0.0000, 0.0000],
             [0.0000, 0.0000]]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Now, I have this architecture:

```
 input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
    n_classes = 10

    model = models.Sequential([
        data_scaling,

       #  data_augmentation,
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),

        *Wavemix Lite block here*

        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'),
    ])

   model.build(input_shape=input_shape)
```

How can I implement the 2D-DWT block in this architecture?

I tried to create a new layer using the class, but without results. I just need to implement the 2D-DWT block such that the architecture works.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the 2D-DWT block as a custom layer in your CNN architecture using the tf.keras.layers.Layer class. The call method of the custom layer class should take in the input tensor and perform the 2D-DWT transformation using the pywt library.

Here's the solution of how you can implement is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pywt

class DWT2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, wavelet='haar', **kwargs):
        super(DWT2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.wavelet = wavelet

    def call(self, input_tensor):
        coeffs = pywt.dwt2(input_tensor, self.wavelet)
        cA, (cH, cV, cD) = coeffs
        return cA, cH, cV, cD

input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
n_classes = 10

model = models.Sequential([
    data_scaling,

    layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),

    DWT2D(),

    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'),
])
model.build(input_shape=input_shape)
```

You can add the custom layer to your architecture by instantiating an object of the DWT2D class and adding it to the model.Sequential list. Once you fit the model, the custom layer will be used to perform the 2D-DWT transformation on the input tensor.

This implementation will return 4 tensors: cA, cH, cV, cD. If you want to use all the 4 tensors in the following layers, you might want to create 4 different layers and pass each tensor to the corresponding layer.

Make sure that the input tensor passed to the call method of the custom layer is of type np.float64 as required by pywt.dwt2 function.